# how to write blocking function in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

hi i am trying to short my urls

```
function shorutrl(link)
{
var linkpost = JSON.stringify({longUrl:link});.

        var optionslink = {
        host: "www.googleapis.com",
        port: 443,
        method: 'POST',
        path: "/urlshortener/v1/url",
        headers: {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
        }
    };

optionslink.headers['Content-Length']=linkpost.length;
var linkreq = https.request(optionsimg, function(res) {
                res.on('data', function (d) {
                linkdata+=d;
                });
                res.on('end', function (x) {
                try { return JSON.parse(linkdata).id; } catch(e){ return link; }
                });
            }).on('error', function (e) {
                //console.log(e.message);
            });
linkreq.write(optionslink);
linkreq.end();
}

function nonworking_givelink()
{
   return shorutrl(txtlinks[Math.floor(Math.random() * txtlinks.length)]);
}

function working_givelink()
{
   return txtlinks[Math.floor(Math.random() * txtlinks.length)];
}
```

nonworking_givelink returns undefined working_givelink returns link as normal

should i write a new function and pass paramters to that and generate new link and pass the paramters to another function is there no any easier way?

Comment: Where is `working_givelink`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't write blocking code in node.js, it goes against the very design of the system.

You need to  pass a callback function which will be called with the new URL within your `.on('end', ...)` block.

Alternatively, wrap this up into a new object which itself emits events, e.g.:

```
var https = require('https');
var events = require('events');

function GoogleShortener() {
    events.EventEmitter.call(this);
};

GoogleShortener.super_ = events.EventEmitter;
GoogleShortener.prototype = Object.create(events.EventEmitter.prototype, {
    constructor: {
        value: GoogleShortener,
        enumerable: false
    }
});

GoogleShortener.prototype.shorten = function(link) {

    var self = this;
    var data = JSON.stringify({longUrl: link});

    var options = {
        hostname: 'www.googleapis.com',
        port: 443,
        path: '/urlshortener/v1/url',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Content-Length': data.length
        }
    };

    var resp = '';

    var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function(d) {
            resp += d;
        }).on('end', function() {
            try {
                var id = JSON.parse(resp).id;
                self.emit('success', id);
            } catch (e) {
                self.emit('error', e);
            }
        });
    }).on('error', function(e) {
        self.emit('error', e);
    });

    req.write(data);
    req.end();

    return self;
};

exports.shorten = function(link) {
    return new GoogleShortener().shorten(link);
};
```

usage:

```
var g = require('gshort');
g.shorten('http://www.google.com/').on('success', function(link) {
     console.log(link)
});
```

Comment: my parameters is more than 1 kb i already pass them to 3-4 for image link, description , text , and for link and i already use return at .on('end' event

Comment: the size of your paramaters is irrelevant, you simply can't write this function the way you have.  You _must_ arrange for an asynchronous function to be called once the final result is known.

Comment: so they must delete return function its not required while its not important what returns

Answer (score 0):

`return` doesn't return from the function you want it to return from. It returns from the function immediately around it. Consider:

```
function foo() {
    var bar = function() {
        return "baz";  // This does _not_ return from `foo`! It returns from `bar`
    }
    bar();
}

console.log(foo())  // undefined
```